# A comand to remove a handler in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I added a handler using this command:

```
stack exec -- yesod add-handler
```

But now I want to remove it.
Is there a command line to remove a handler in Yesod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command to remove a handler, since it would be quite a destructive and risky thing to do, and since removing a handler is quite simple, just

- remove it from the .cabal file,
- remove it from the Application.hs file and
- delete the actual handler file

And you should be good to go :) You can read what `add-handler` does [in the Yesod book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template#scaffolding-and-the-site-template_handler_modules).